# How to join a subquery to itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

How do can you join a subquery onto itself? I'd like to do something like the following.

```
SELECT 
    four.src AS start, four.dest AS layover, f.dest AS destination
FROM 
    ( SELECT 1 AS src, 2 as dest union all select 2, 3 ) AS four
JOIN
    four AS f 
ON f.src = four.dest
```

However the query above gives me the error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>   Invalid object name 'four'.

I'd rather not have to store it as a variable or view etc first since this is part of a monolithic query (this is itself a subquery and its part of a series of `UNIONS`) and I do not want to make sure that there are no impacting joins elsewhere that relate.

The force behind this change is that `four`used to be a simple lookup but now for this query the values have to be calculated.

---

**PS** - this is a simplified example, in my case the subquery for `four` is a hundred lines long

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of [CTE (Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in this scenario. Here, you need not to store this result in any temporary objects.

```
;WITH four AS (
SELECT 1 AS src, 2 as dest 
union all 
select 2, 3
)

SELECT F1.src AS start, F1.dest AS layover, f2.dest AS destination
FROM four F1
INNER JOIN four F2 ON F1.src = F2.dest
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a temp table.

```
Declare @Temp(src int, desc int);
INSERT INTO @Temp(src,desc)
VALUES
(SELECT 1 AS src, 2 as dest union all select 2, 3)
SELECT * FROM @Temp t1
INNER JOIN @Temp t2 ON t1.src = t2.dest
```

Comment: > I'd rather not have to store it as a variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it again. You alias 'four' can only be called in 'Select','Where', 'have', 'On'etc. conditions only and NOT as table in joins until and unless it's a table name in itself

```
SELECT 
    four.src AS start, four.dest AS layover, f.dest AS destination
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS src, 2 as dest union all select 2, 3 ) AS four
JOIN
    (SELECT 1 AS src, 2 as dest union all select 2, 3 ) AS f 
ON f.src = four.dest
```